# VBScript Regular Expression Insert Line

Tags: regex, vbscript

I try to insert a line between 2 specific lines in a files with VBScript :

```
# Ligne 1
# Ligne 2
```

=>

```
# Ligne 1
# Ligne 1 bis
# Ligne 2
```

My script code is :

```
Dim regEx
Set regEx = New RegExp   

regEx.Pattern = "# Ligne 1\r\n# Ligne 2"      
regEx.Pattern = patrn       
regEx.IgnoreCase = not Casse   
regEx.Global = True  

RegExpReplace=regEx.Replace(Source,"# Ligne 1\r\n# Ligne 1 bis\r\n# Ligne 2")
```

The expression has been found but the replacement text is bad.
The result is :

```
# Ligne 1\r\n# Ligne 1 bis\r\n# Ligne 2
```

I tried :

```
regEx.Pattern = "^# Ligne 1$\r\n^# Ligne 2$"   
regEx.IgnoreCase = not Casse   
regEx.Global = True  
regEx.Multiline = True
RegExpReplace=regEx.Replace(Source,"^# Ligne 1$\r\n^# Ligne 1 bis$\r\n^# Ligne 2$")
```

The result is :

```
^# Ligne 1$\r\n^# Ligne 1 bis$\r\n^# Ligne 2$
```

Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RegExpReplace=regEx.Replace(Source,"# Ligne 1" & vbCrLf & " # Ligne 1 bis" & vbCrLf &"# Ligne 2")
```

You replace the **string** found matching the *regular expression* with the **string** indicated as replacement (with the exception of capture groups placeholders). Inside a VBScript `\r\n` has not the same meaning than in a regular expression, so, if you need to include a carriage return and line feed you need to directly concatenate them